# how to work with laravel in team?

Tags: php, laravel, github

For example, i have mac  and create new repository on github and my collabarators has linux, but they can't run this project after pull.

Please, give me some advices, how can we work in team via github?

Comment: Use GIT or any versioning control system.

Comment: whats the error they are getting ?

Comment: If i (mac) redact this project, the guy who use linux can't run it

Comment: You both can use homestead to have the same "server" https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead

Comment: HP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/new_project/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/new_project/artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/new_project/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/new_project/artisan on line 18

Comment: Thanks man) I'll try this

Comment: "_but they can't run this project after pull_" They surely get some error messages or warnings. Post them. Also, make sure all of your devs set up ... nevermind @lewis4u already posted what should be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few special things your team mate needs to do in order to be able to run this project:

1. he needs to create his own .env file and setup the database connection
2. run composer install (to download all packages used in that application)
3. run php artisan migrate (if there are any migrations)
4. run php artisan serve /or/ if he uses MAMP or something he needs to configure it there...

The main access folder is "your_app_name"/public